# Why are there so few Massive Online Open Courses (MOOCs) for the core college curriculum for a BS in Math?

Tags: mathematics, mooc

I've noticed that there are very few Massive Online Open Course (MOOCs) that cover the core college math curriculum, for example

- Basic integral and differential calculus
- ODE
- PDE
- Linear Algebra
- Abstract Algebra
- Probability
- Statistics
- Combinatorics
- Symbolic logic
- Complex Variables
- Real Analysis

Anyone care to speculate what are the factors involved that make these bread-and-butter topics so much harder to MOOC-size or less easier to motivate professors to produce than Introduction to Water and Climate or Cybersecurity Fundamentals?  I.e. it seems that specialized niche topics receive far more pedagogical energy than basic ones.  But I know as a student that I would very much appreciate having the core fundamental topics available in MOOC form.

Comment: https://nptel.ac.in  in India, it has a lot. It's in English, you can try

Comment: https://mooculus.osu.edu/

Comment: Khan Academy has got [differential](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus), [integral](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus), and [multivariable](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus) calculus, [stats, probability, basic combinatorics](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability), [basic linear algebra](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra), and [basic PDEs](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations), including exercises - all for free, without ads, and without selling your data. (Disclaimer: I work there.)

Comment: I would also like to mention [Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/)

Comment: I think most of the undergrad BA/BS math curriculum at MIT and Harvard are available through their online open course platforms. You don't have direct access to professors or TAs, but there are many resources and online forums where you can get help while working through the material.

Answer (score 31):

I feel that this is heavily driven by the job-market. Topics in academic mathematics do not possess the necessary buzzword status to make MOOCs profitable. Very few job postings ever ask for competency in abstract algebra, real and complex analysis, basic calculus, etc. Many job postings want machine learning, "big data," "artificial intelligence," virtual reality, etc.

When a MOOC advertises its wares, very few people are going to click on an ad that tells them they can learn abstract algebra and category theory. A MOOC teaching Python and "data science" intrigues a number of people who believe that if they can just learn a little Python, all of the sudden Facebook will pay them $150k a year to do data science.

Answer (score 17):

First, as @DC 541 has already pointed out, the audience for relatively advanced math courses is much smaller than the audience for business and software courses, so why would somebody go to the effort?

Second, while having the lectures available for streaming is very nice, the real meat of any upper division math course is going to be the homework and exam problems. For more computational courses it's possible to set up sophisticated automated graders that essentially run a bunch of unit tests on the submitted code. I don't think grading proofs can be automated in the same way.

That means grading the homework is going to be a bottleneck. If you were to employ an army of TAs to grade a thousand real analysis homework assignments it would cost a fortune. MOOCS have tried to get around this for some subjects using a published rubric and grading by peers. I'm not convinced it works very well, and I've never seen it used for a math course.

Comment: I've been in advanced MOOCs with peer grading and it actually is fun and works rather well.

Comment: Also I don't think grad schools for example do a very good job of screening people's math skills (for remedial purposes, not acceptance).  I think it would be an interesting and fun challenge to write an automated grading system that "interviewed" a person and posed various problems to automatically assess their competency in a variety of math skills.

Comment: I happen to work in a quantitative area and we have to do this every other day: assess the math skills of job candidates.  If you can do that online automatically, you can teach core advanced math skills online automatically.

Comment: @LarsEricson: The upper division math courses aren't quantitative courses at all.  They are courses fundamentally about logic, not about quantities.

Comment: There are formalized, computer-interpreted mathematical proving languages out there that could (probably) be automated and checked for consistency. Of course, you might need a whole separate course in how to use one of them...

Comment: @KRyan Would you please tell me an example of computer-interpreted mathematical proof of Sylow theorem? I'll be very interested to read it. Or an example of an automated proof of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? Thanks.

Comment: @scaaahu see [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-452.pdf) for example. I don't think KRyan 's suggestion is impossible, just not very useful for helping students who are pretty new to human readable proofs, let alone formal languages for writing proofs.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Thanks. That's quite a bit stuff for me to read for the rest of today.

Comment: @scaaahu To be perfectly honest, I am not a mathematician and know very little on the subject—literally all I remember seeing was an interesting-looking project seeking more proofs written in such a language, to build up its library of proofs. I believe it was on the Mathematics Stack Exchange, if you’re interested in searching for it. So I know it exists, but I have no idea how detailed it is, or whether anyone has written (or if it is even possible to write) a proof of Sylow theorem—for that matter, I don’t even know what Sylow theorem is. It was meant as trivia, not as a serious suggestion.

Comment: @scaaahu: I know very little about this topic, but a search for [formalized mathematics](https://www.google.com/search?q="formalized+mathematics") will bring up a lot of results. In particular, there's the online journal [**Formalized Mathematics**](http://mizar.org/fm/) ([description of journal](http://mizar.org/fm/about.htm) and the associated [Mizar Mathematical Library](http://mizar.org/library/)). I became aware of this research effort back in the mid 1990s when searching the internet for math words/phrases of interest to me and hits to articles in this journal often showed up.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Same here. That's why I asked for an example. I read the cited example above a little bit. They had to prove 270 some theorems before they were able to prove Sylow theorem. I am wondering which way is better, teach the students the formal language and fundamental concepts and let them come up with the automated proof, or the traditional way. Will the future math education be like this or we keep the way we have been educated? Of course, this is way off-topic. May be it's a good one on Math Edu SE?

Comment: I would like an automated version of this book, which probes my skills, gives me an assessment/map of my training/skills in relevant areas, and then tries to teach me what I don't know: https://smile.amazon.com/Frequently-Questions-Interviews-Pocket-Guides/dp/0979757649